# intent://でアプリにパラメータを渡したい

Tags: android

Chromeアプリからandroidのintentスキーマを使い、アプリがあればアプリを立ち上げて、アプリがなければマーケットに飛ぶことまでは出来て居ます。
ただ、そのアプリの特定のページに移動する事が出来ない状態です。
おそらく、受け渡しするときのパラメーターがうまく引き渡せていないと思います。

なので、アプリ内の特定ページに移動できません。

パラメーターの受け渡しの設定がわかれば教えてください。

ちなみに今のパスは
intent://ファイルのパス#Intent;package=マーケットのユニークID(バンドルID?);scheme=アプリスキーム名;end;
こんな感じです。

宜しくお願いします。

Comment: AndroidManifest.xmlを掲載することはできますか？

Answer (score 2):

「アプリ内の特定のページ」は「特定のActivity」と読み替えさせて回答させていただきます。

あとは
https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents
辺りに記載がありますが、「ファイルのパス」という概念はありません。

一応下記にも例を記載します。

リンク側：([]は説明用括弧で実際には不要です。)

```
<a href="intent://[host名]/#Intent;scheme=[scheme名];package=[package名];category=android.intent.category.BROWSABLE;action=android.intent.action.VIEW;end;">Test Link</a>
```

Manifest側

```
<activity android:name=".起動したいActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="scheme名"
            android:host="host名" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Action/Categoryは必要に応じて追加可能ですが、manifest側のcategory.BROWSABLEは必須のようです。

アプリを起動したいだけならばschemeとhostだけで起動可能なはずです。
packageをつけることで、アプリがインストールされていない場合に該当packageを探しに行きます。

---

その他、extra情報等をつけたい場合などにのintent:スキーマ文字列の組み立て方は下記コマンドが便利です。

```
adb shell am to-intent-uri
```

https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html#IntentSpec