# AndroidのGmailアプリにおける、URLスキーム利用について

Tags: android, gmail

お世話になっております。

現在、AndroidのGmail側でHTMLタイプのメールに、URLスキームのリンクを貼ってアプリ起動できないかを試しております。

しかし、なぜかリンクがテキスト形式になってしまい、タップできない状態です。
※iphoneのGmailアプリだとリンクタップでアプリが起動できる。

具体的にはHTMLタイプのメールを以下にして、送信しております。

```
<html>
    <body>
        <a href='comgooglemaps:'>アプリ起動</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

解決方法がありましたら、ご教示ください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URLスキームをリンクとして認識させる方法ではありませんが、下記のようなサービスを利用することでGmailから任意のアプリを起動させるという目的は達成できるかもしれません。
https://branch.io/

参考
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38778618/cant-get-gmail-for-android-to-open-a-custom-url-scheme-or-an-intent-url

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。提示していただいたサービスを利用しようとも考えましたが、今回はWebブラウザ立ち上げ→再度アプリに戻すという方法をとることになりました。※googleのアプリがそのようになっているため。

Answer (score 0):

推測ですが、Gmailアプリがリンクだと認識できないためテキスト形式の表示になっていると考えられます。

下記のように`//`を追加してみてはどうでしょうか？

```
<a href='comgooglemaps://'>アプリ起動</a>
```

または、ホスト部を追加してみてください。

```
<a href='comgooglemaps://host/'>アプリ起動</a>
```

余談ですが、上記のリンクの場合、アプリがインストールされていない場合はエラーページが表示される可能性があるので、[こちらの回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/32082/21081)を参考にしてみてください。

Comment: 素早いご回答、ありがとうございます。  ご指摘の通り、//を入れてみましたが、やはりテキストになってしまいます。また、host部を追加しましたが同じ結果になってしまいました。

Comment: [こちらのやり方](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/32071/intent-%E3%81%A7%E3%82%A2%E3%83%97%E3%83%AA%E3%81%AB%E3%83%91%E3%83%A9%E3%83%A1%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E3%82%92%E6%B8%A1%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84/32082#32082)はどうでしょうか？

Comment: <a href='intent://199.…/#Intent;scheme=comgooglemaps:;category=android.intent.category.BROWSABLE;action=android.intent.action.VIEW;end;'>Test Link</a>　左記のような形式で試してみましたが、やはりandroidのみテキストで表示されてしまいます。。。